# program to find the sum of digits

Tags: c

I can't figure out the problem in this:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int a,b,count ;
    count =0;
    printf("enter the value for a ");
    scanf("%d ",&a);
    while(a>0)
    {
        b=a%10;
        count=b+count;
        a=a/10; 

        printf ("hence the simplified result is %d",count);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Properly indent your code; on SO, add an extra 4 spaces to format it as code. See the difference it makes?

Comment: What problem? Be as precise as you can be: post the actual output, post what output you expected.

Comment: Also, when describing a problem give the expected behavior and actual behavior (which includes error codes, if any). This lets us know the specific problem you're working on.

Comment: Start up a debugger (like gdb) and step the code. Se how the variables change with every step, it will help you understand what the code does :)

Comment: Er... What makes you think there's a problem in this? Please, clarify what you mean when you say "problem". Without it your question makes no sense whatsoever.

Comment: There is basically two logical errors with the program. One with `scanf()`, and other is the `printf()` should be outside `while`. Read it here [How to find sum of digits in C](http://codeforwin.blogspot.in/2015/06/c-program-to-calculate-sum-of-digits.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a [silent killer](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/001310.html) in your code:

```
scanf("%d ",&a);
```

The extra space in your scanf will make entering numbers harder: this will match `12<space>`, but not `12`. Replace the `"%d "` with `"%d"`.

Comment: My previous comment was incorrect when I stated that there's no problem with `"%d "` format. There's a problem, although it is different from what the above answer discribes. The `"%d "` will match `12` input perfectly fine, meaning that it will successfuly read the 12, since the space after the `%d` has no effect on the way `%d` is interpreted. However, the trailing `" "` in the format string will direct `scanf` to continue to eat-up whitespace after reading the number until a non-white space or EOF is encountered. This makes no sensea and will be confusing when enering numbers manually.

Comment: @AndreyT: On my system at least, `scanf("%d ")` does not return if you input `1<return>`

Comment: @Andomar: That's what I'm talking about. As I said, it doesn't return because `scanf` continues to consume whitespace and `<return>` is whitespace. If you input, say. `1a<return>` it will return immediately and the value of a will be successfully read as `1`.

Comment: @Andomar: You said above that it will not match `12`. This is incorrect. It will match `12` perfectly well, if it is really just `12`, i.e. there's an EOF or a non-whitespace after that `12`. The problem is that in addition to `12` it can match `12<a-lot-of-whitespace>`, so `scanf` will no return until it finds the end of that whitespace.

Comment: @AndreyT: Interesting comments, that certainly explains it in detail

Answer (score 3):

You do not terminate your `printf()` with a "\n". The output stream (stdout) is, usually, line buffered. That means that incomplete lines need not be printed unless you force them with `fflush()`. But there's no need for that.

Simply add a "\n" to your `printf()`

```
        printf("hence the simplified result is %d\n", count);
```

Comment: I couldn't determine his problem from his post. Anyhow, this will make his program "better".

Comment: It will solve one problem. Hence a useful answer since the question was a bit vague.

Answer (score 2):

One issue is you print the count with every loop, rather than than after the loop.

Not an issue, but C has arithmetic assignment (aka [compound assignment](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iadthelp/v7r0/topic/com.ibm.etools.iseries.langref.doc/as400clr131.htm)) operators that can be more readable. For example, `a /= 10` is equivalent to `a = a/10`.

Answer (score 1):

I think the printf statement should be outside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Move the printf out side the loop. That will fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int a,b,count ;
    count =0;
    printf("enter the value for a ");
    scanf("%d",&a);
    while(a>0)
    {
        b=a%10;
        count=b+count;
        a=a/10; 
    } 
    printf ("hence the simplified result is %d",count);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Try loosing the " " in the scanf as well.. :)