# Add the digits of each element in an multidimensional array

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a 2 dimensional array. I'm trying to add the digits of each element in the array and find the sum.

For example :

consider my array is: `a[2][2] = { {15,11}, {13,21} }`.

Now for the element `15` i need to add `1+5` and the result `6` placed in the same position.
and for element `11` `1+1` and place the result `2` in the same position. And the same for all other elements.

Following is my code.

```
int main ()
{

   int a[3][2] = { {19,11}, {13,21}, {12,14}};
   int i, j;
   int digit1,digit2,sum1=0,sum2=0,rem1,rem2;

   for ( i = 0; i < 3; i++ )
   {

      for ( j = 0; j < 2; j++ )
      {
         digit1 = a[i];
         rem1 = digit1%10;
         sum1 = sum1 + rem1;
         digit1 = digit1/10;

         digit2 = a[j];
         rem2 = digit2%10;
         sum2 = sum2 + rem2;
         digit2 = digit2/10;

         printf("\nthe sum of i: ", sum1);
        printf("\nthe sum of j: ", sum2);

      }


   }
   return 0;
}
```

But from above code I'm not getting the sum.

I am kinda new to this and got stuck here. Here's the code in [EDITOR](http://codepad.org/pfru1SN9).

Comment: Here's an SO post for the core functionality: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1713931/program-to-find-the-sum-of-digits

Comment: @RSahu I think i have followed the same logic in my code too. But when it comes to arrays, i'm not sure how to implement it.

Comment: @smashIT could you please check my answer? I think this is what you wanted. Please check. And feel free to ask if you have some questions.

Comment: To clarify, if the entry was 98765 then the intended sum is `35`, not `8`?  (your examples all featured single-digit sums)

Comment: @MattMcNabb I just need one addition. Dont need to add again if there are more than one digit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its simple. Do the following -

```
//Assuming the array is a[3][2]

for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
for(int j=0;j<2;j++)
{
  int sum = 0;
  while(a[i][j])
  {
   sum+=a[i][j]%10;
   a[i][j]/=10;
  }
   a[i][j]=sum;
}
```

Comment: I tried this. But while printing the sum, it seems to be empty.

Comment: Can You give your code here? just post it with the array :)

Comment: @smashIT are you still facing problem? You can show me your code. I think this should work.

Comment: `int main() {

    int a[3][2] = { {19,11}, {13,21}, {12,14}};
    int i, j;

    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
            int sum = 0;
            while (a[i][j]) {
                sum += a[i][j] % 10;
                a[i][j] /= 10;
            }
            printf("\nsum is", sum);
            a[i][j] = sum;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}`

Comment: wait I am checking it.

Comment: use printf("\nsum is %d", sum); instead of printf("\nsum is", sum); :P

Comment: Does it serve your purpose?

Comment: Yeah. It does the job

Answer (score 2):

Define a function to compute the sum of the digits of an integer.

```
int getSumOfDigits(int n)
{
   int ret = 0;
   while ( n > 0 )
   {
      ret += (n%10);
      n /= 10;
   }
   return ret;
}
```

Use the function in the `for` loop.

```
for ( i = 0; i < 3; i++ )
{
   for ( j = 0; j < 2; j++ )
   {
      a[i][j] = getSumOfDigits(a[i][j]);
   }
}
```

Comment: The array is a[3][2] but your loop is 2*2. It will not work. Please change the loop :)

Comment: @Naseef, thanks for the clarification. The OP has a 2x2 array in the description and a 3x2 array in the code.

Comment: Yeah. I did the same thing while writing my answer. Fortunately before posting it I checked the post again. And furthermore I think this is a simple task and I think the user is a beginner so there is a chance that user will get confused by seeing an extra function to calculate the sum of digits. It can be done in 3-4 lines without using an extra function. Though using function you can make the code modular and it is a good practice :)

Answer (score 0):

Inside for loop put this code instead of your code it will work

```
 for ( j = 0; j < 2; j++ )
  {
     sum1=0;
     while(a[i][j]){
     sum1=sum1+(a[i][j]%10);
     a[i][j]=a[i][j]/10;
     }
     a[i][j]=sum1;

     printf("\nthe sum of [%d][%d]: %d", i,j,sum1);
}
```

Comment: What will be the output if the number is 115. I don't think your code will work when the number has more than 2 digits. Please check your code for a[3][2] = { {159,121}, {153,3521}, {1552,152534}};

Comment: He didn't specified any number. So it should be generalized. Unfortunately your code is not generalized. Though somehow it got accepted.

Comment: @Sathish I thought that was obvious